# Unable to get table to load in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a ViewController in which I put another small UIView in the middle where I have placed a TableView but not sure how to display data from an array in this table, any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to load the table using this code:

```
-(void) animateResults {


_resultsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Scored %d", runningScore ];
resultsTable.delegate = self;
resultsTable.dataSource = self;
[self.resultsTable registerClass:[resultsViewCell self] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"resultsListCell"];
[self.resultsTable reloadData];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    _resultsView.frame = self.view.frame;


} completion:^(BOOL finished){

   NSLog(@"%@", questionsArray);

}];


}
```

I am using a Custom Cell in my TableView to load an NSMutableArray. I have tried Using this code for the table view:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(resultsViewCell *)tableView {
//Return number of sections
return 1;

}

//get number of rows by counting number of challenges
-(NSInteger)tableView:(resultsViewCell *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return questionsArray.count;
}


//setup cells in tableView
-(resultsViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//setup cell
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"resultsListCell";

resultsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

NSDictionary *results = [questionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *resultsName = [results objectForKey:@"answers"];

BOOL correct = [[results objectForKey:@"correct"] boolValue];

if (!correct) {
    cell.resultsIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BlackIconLock.png"];
}

else{
    cell.resultsIcon.image = nil;
}

cell.resultsName.text = resultsName;

return cell;
}
```

But the _resultsView does not load not sure why. I've got a lot of great help thus far and I really do appreciate it. I've been stuck at this point for about 2 weeks. Please help!

Comment: Check if the `_resultView` is `nil`.

Comment: Sorry I'm New to this learning as I go, how would I check that? sorry again for noobness

Comment: Right at the beginning of `animateResults` add the line `NSLog(@"resultsView: %@", _resultsView)`, run the app and look at the console output. If it prints `resultsView: (null)`, the view is nil.

Comment: You have to initialize the view before you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY! got this figured out My intention was to have a UITableView load inside of a UIView. I tried to drag and drop the TableView delegate and datasource on the ViewController but every time the app loaded it crashed. So I moved the table view delegate and datasource to the UIView load method here: I tried using this Method to do so.

```
 -(void) animateResults {
 //this part of my method actually worked it displayed the final score from a predifined variable.
 _resultsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Scored %d", runningScore ];
 //i tried using this to set my UITableView delegate & dataSource when the method was initiated instead of UIViewController load.
 resultsTable.delegate = self;
 resultsTable.dataSource = self;
//used this code to register UIViewCell that was nonexistent, 
//i declared *CellIdentifier = @"resultsListCell" and it should have 
//been *CellIdentifier = @"resultsCell". so i received an error used this code to solve it.
//duh. cell don't exist must not be the cell you created.My Bad.
 [self.resultsTable registerClass:[resultsViewCell self]   forCellReuseIdentifier:@"resultsListCell"];
 //this code worked but after debugging i found out there was no data to load.
 [self.resultsTable reloadData];
 //was desperate at this point not sure why i put this in.
 [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
 //this also worked loads my UIView.
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
_resultsView.frame = self.view.frame;

} completion:^(BOOL finished){

NSLog(@"%@", questionsArray);

}];

}
```

So My solution was frustrating in it's simplicity. The reason my app crashed when I tried to drag and drop the dataSource and delegate, was because of the mislabeled "static NSString *CellIdentifier", So make sure your cell identifier is correct! Not knowing this I attempted to load the UITableView dataSource and delegate in the above method. I have since modified the above method to this.

```
-(void) animateResults {

//populate label
_resultsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Scored %d", runningScore   ];

//reload table
[self.resultsTable reloadData];

//Load View
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

    _resultsView.frame = self.view.frame;

} completion:^(BOOL finished){

    NSLog(@"%@", questionsArray);

}];
}
```

This trimmed down code works because I connected the dataSource and delegate to UIViewController. Doing this loads the table when the UIViewController loads so theres no need to do so programmatically. Also, correcting the mislabeled cell identifier eliminated the need for the registerClass variable. Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using above xcode 7, you will use UIContainerView middle to ViewController in storyboard, its automatically Embed the UITableView to containerView, example [image: use this way its embed and load array will be showed]

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload data in `animateResults` in `completion block`. something like this,

```
completion:^(BOOL finished){

     NSLog(@"%@", questionsArray);
     [self.resultsTable reloadData];

}];
```

Comment: i did that and received this error -[UITableViewCell resultsIcon]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: are you setting tableview class from interface builder? If yes then why are you registering class in animateResult method?

Comment: so remove [self.resultsTable registerClass:[resultsViewCell self] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"resultsListCell"];? if I do that then i get Unknown class resultsView in Interface Builder file. at the beginning of my debug. Also now receive a UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance